# Annotate a values() query in Django

Tags: django, annotate

My `RelatedModel` has a foreign key field pointing to a `Product` object. I'm trying to count the number of `RelatedModel`s per `Product` UUID.

```
RelatedModel.objects.all().values(fk_product__uuid).annotate(total=Count('id'))
```

This gives me:

```
[
{'total': 3, 'fk_product__uuid': UUID('195b6aa8-6a57-62c6-89d1-3397bf69d928')},
{'total': 7, 'fk_product__uuid': UUID('2a6a6a98-1a17-4cca-8111-2212b951003a')},
...
]
```

I'd prefer that my UUID keys just be called "uuid", but I'm having difficulty getting `annotate` to work on the reverse relation. Is there a way to do this without post-processing the list?

Comment: Oh great! Thanks Shang, I didn't search on "rename", just "annotate". The answer is to use `django.db.models.F`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For reference following Shang's suggestion (tested and working):

```
q = Product_r.objects.all().annotate(uuid=F('fk_product__uuid')).values('uuid').annotate(total=Count('id')).order_by('total')
```